# c# and Regex: How do I make a match?

Tags: c#, regex

Aloha,

I need to match `page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=` but not match `http://random address/page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=`

Right now I'm just doing a simple resting replace with `strContent.Replace("page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=", "page.aspx/Show/");` but to avoid the above i think I need to move to regular expressions.

**Edit:** Sorry i was a little short on details The current replace works because I was not taking into account that the address being modified should only be relative addresses, not absolute. I need to catch all relative addresses that match `page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=` and convert that string into `page.aspx/Show/`.

The `.StartsWith` and `^` wont work because I an looking in a string that is a full html page. So I need to be able to convert:

```
<p>Hello, please click <a href="page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=10">here</a>.</p>
```

into

```
<p>Hello, please click <a href="page/Show/10">here</a>.</p>
```

but not convert

```
<p>Hello, please click <a href="http://some address/page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=10">here</a>.</p>
```

I used an A tag for my example but I need to convert IMG tags as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it must be relative address? Your example is not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [`ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) rather than a regular expression because this will work even if the parameters are in a different order.

Otherwise you can use [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) to test if there is a match.

If you want to use a regular expression you need to use `^` and also escape all the special characters in your string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^page\.aspx\?cmd=Show&id=");
```

If you don't want to escape the characters yourself you can get [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to do it for you:

```
string urlToMatch = "page.aspx?cmd=Show&id=";
Regex regex = new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(urlToMatch));
```

Comment: This would work if strContent was only the url, its not. Sorry, I've updated my question with more detail of the situation.

Comment: @justin808: Did you try `\"` instead of `^`? However now you've updated your question I see that you are using this for HTML. I'd recommend an HTML parser to find the `href` attributes, and **not** a regular expression. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a ^ to look for start of line. 
... Or you can be cool and use a negative lookbehind `(?<!http://.*?/)`. ;)

See http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View6BD88331-350D-429F-AB49-D18E90E0E705.htm